# An instance of analyzer cannot be created - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis'

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I was building a Source Generator, and upon packaging it up on Nuget and then using it in another project, I was receiving this warning:

> warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer TomLonghurst.AllOf.SourceGenerator.AllOfGenerator cannot be created from C:.nuget\packages\tomlonghurst.allof\1.4.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\TomLonghurst.AllOf.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

At the time of this post, I've got the .NET 6 SDK installed.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this here in case this helps someone else. I wasted a few hours due to this.

What I've theorised is (Correct me if I'm wrong) is that the .NET Compiler is built with a version of 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis', but an older one than the one I was referencing in my source generator. Therefore the compiler itself can't find version 4.3.0 because it was built with an older package version.

I simply downgraded that package from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1 in my source generator, published a new version of my package, and voila, all was running successfully.

Comment: since it's not clear what you tried, common tasks working with SGs involve deleting `bin` and `obj` folders, rebuild and restarting VS to get the SG consumers running or you might also have to clear the nuget cache.

Comment: @PatrickBeynio What do you mean it's not clear? I said I downgraded the package versions of any Microsoft.CodeAnalysis packages.